# In what situations is the CopyOnWriteArrayList suitable?

Tags: java, collections

I am learning about the [CopyOnWriteArrayList](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CopyOnWriteArrayList.html) class.

- What is the purpose of copying a new array?
- Is it for other threads to read the array?

So if a system has high concurrency and most of the threads' actions are reading not writing, it is better to use `CopyOnWriteArrayList`.

Answer (score 103, accepted):

As stated on this [link](http://java67.blogspot.in/2012/09/what-is-copyonwritearraylist-in-java-example-vs-arraylist.html):

[CopyOnWriteArrayList](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CopyOnWriteArrayList.html) is a concurrent Collection class introduced in Java 5 Concurrency API along with its popular cousin `ConcurrentHashMap` in Java.

`CopyOnWriteArrayList` implements List interface like `ArrayList`, `Vector` and `LinkedList` but it is a thread-safe collection and it achieves its thread-safety in a slightly different way than Vector or other thread-safe collection class.

> As name suggest CopyOnWriteArrayList creates copy of underlying
> ArrayList with every mutation operation e.g. add or set. Normally
> CopyOnWriteArrayList is very expensive because it involves costly
> Array copy with every write operation but **its very efficient if you
> have a List where Iteration outnumber mutation** e.g. you mostly need to
> iterate the ArrayList and don't modify it too often.

> **Iterator of CopyOnWriteArrayList is fail-safe and doesn't throw
> ConcurrentModificationException** even if underlying
> CopyOnWriteArrayList is modified once Iteration begins because
> Iterator is operating on separate copy of ArrayList. Consequently all
> the updates made on CopyOnWriteArrayList is not available to Iterator.

To get the most updated version do a new read like `list.iterator();`

That being said, updating this collection a lot will kill performance. If you tried to sort a `CopyOnWriteArrayList` you'll see the list throws an `UnsupportedOperationException` (the sort invokes set on the collection N times). You should only use this read when you are doing upwards of 90+% reads.

Comment: And if you need to add items very frequently to the list and sometimes need to remove all. Do you think the 'synchronized' way is the better approach?

Comment: You can consider `java.util.concurrent` package over `Collections.synchronizedList`.

Comment: I'm already using it. But it seems to work just when I combine with the old `synchronized` keyword.

Comment: Just read here and now I got it. We need no use `synchronized` keyword when you iterate a `Set`, even when we use `Collections.synchronizedList`.

Comment: ".. even if underlying CopyOnWriteArrayList is modified once Iteration begins because Iterator is operating on separate copy of ArrayList" Do you mean, because the modification actually is made on a separate copy?

Comment: @KorayTugay Yes, It iterates over a copy of original list.

Comment: Can it throw `ConcurrentModificationException ` if I update the copy as I iterate over it (on the same thread)?

Comment: @stdout - no it won't throw ConcurrentModificationException . It is a fail safe collection which uses a seperate copy for iteration.

Comment: One mistake here , "sort a CopyOnWriteArrayList you'll see the list throws an UnsupportedOperationException ",  NO,NO, call sort method of CopyOnWriteArrayList will works good and also I have read the source code and executed a test.

Comment: From java8, you can sort  CopyOnWriteArrayList using cowlist.sort(null) with null comparator

Answer (score 28):

> What is the purpose of coping a new array?

Copying the underlying array guarantees that any iteration of the data structure is safe as the iteration is occurring over an essentially immutable "snapshot" of the data.

> Is it for other threads to read the array?

Sort of. More specifically, it is for every thread to be able to safely iterate the array without fear of a `ConcurrentModificationException` or other unknown/undefined behavior.

> So if a system is high concurrency and most of the threads' actions are reading not writing, it is better to use CopyOnWriteArrayList. Am I right?

No. Only if most of the threads' actions are iterations over the list. If most of the activities are random access based reads, a `ReadWriteLock` might be better.

From the javadoc of `CopyOnWriteArrayList`

> This is ordinarily too costly, but may be more efficient than alternatives when **traversal** operations vastly outnumber mutations, and is useful when you cannot or don't want to synchronize **traversals**, yet need to preclude interference among concurrent threads.

Comment: could you explain why `ReadWriteLock` might be better?

Comment: Because the `CopyOnWriteArrayList` is for safe traversals. The cost of using it is duplicating the underlying array of references for each modification and possibly retaining multiple copies for threads iterating over stale versions of the structure. A `ReadWriteLock` would allow multiple readers and still let the occasional writer perform the necessary modifications.