# Thread safe access to arraylist: two producer one consumer. Lock object is enough?

Tags: java, android, multithreading, arraylist, locking

I have two thread that can produce value and add it in a arraylist,
and other thread can access to it to read a value.

My problem is that the producer can access to the list in the same time that the consumer use data.

This is my code :

```
 public class CommandTree
 {  

Lock lock = new ReentrantLock();

ArrayList<Command> cmdToSend = null;
JSONObject sendCmdMap;

public CommandTree(JSONObject sendCmdMap)
{
    this.cmdToSend = new ArrayList<Command>();
    this.sendCmdMap = sendCmdMap;
}

private synchronized void addMacroCmd(String macro, int fmt, int tgt, int sid,int count,JSONArray sli,String paramName,JSONObject params,int function)
{

    boolean check = false;
    int i = 0;

    lock.lock();
        try
        {
            for(i=0; i<cmdToSend.size(); i++)
            {
                if(cmdToSend.get(i).getMacroName().equalsIgnoreCase(macro))
                {
                    check = true;
                    break;
                }
            }

            if(check == false)
            {
                cmdToSend.add(new Command(macro,fmt,tgt,sid,count,function,sli));
            }

            if(paramName != null)
            {
                if(check)
                    cmdToSend.get(i).setParameter(paramName,params);
                else
                    cmdToSend.get(cmdToSend.size()-1).setParameter(paramName,params);
            }
        }
        finally
        {
            lock.unlock();
        }
}


private void addParameter(String macro,int fmt, int tgt, int sid,int count,JSONArray sli,String paramName,JSONObject params,int function)
{
    lock.lock();
    try
    {
        this.addMacroCmd(macro, fmt, tgt, sid, count,sli, paramName,params,function);
    }
    finally
    {
        lock.unlock();
    }

}

public int getSize()
{
    return cmdToSend.size();
}

public void reset()
{
    lock.lock();
    try
    {
        cmdToSend.clear();
    }
    finally
    {
        lock.unlock();
    }

}

/*
public Command getNextCommandInLoop()
{
    return cmdToSend.;
}
*/
public Command getNextCommand(int i)
{
    Command result;

    lock.lock();
    try
    {
        result = cmdToSend.get(i);
    }
    finally
    {
        lock.unlock();
    }

    return result;
}

public synchronized boolean populateCommandTree(String i,String target) throws JSONException
{
    JSONObject tgtCmd = (JSONObject) sendCmdMap.get(target);
    JSONObject cmdObject;

    Iterator<String> iter = tgtCmd.keys();

    while (iter.hasNext()) 
    {
        String key = iter.next();

        if(key.equalsIgnoreCase(i))
        {
            //it is a general commands
            JSONObject macro = (JSONObject)tgtCmd.opt(key);

            cmdObject = (JSONObject) macro.opt("cmd");


            addMacroCmd(key,cmdObject.optInt("fmt"),cmdObject.optInt("tgt"),cmdObject.optInt("sid"),cmdObject.optInt("count"),cmdObject.optJSONArray("sli"),null,null,macro.optInt("function"));

            return true;
        }   
        else
        {
            //It is a parameter, we have to search its general command

            cmdObject = (JSONObject)tgtCmd.opt(key);

            if(cmdObject == null)
            {
                continue;
            }

            JSONObject parameter = cmdObject.optJSONObject("Parameter");

            if( parameter == null)
            {
                //There isn't the requested command, we iterate on the next one
                continue;
            }
            else
            {

                if(((JSONObject) parameter).optJSONObject(i) != null)
                {
                    JSONObject cmdStructure = (JSONObject)cmdObject.opt("cmd");
                    //We have found the  command, save it in commandSendCache
                    addMacroCmd(key,cmdStructure.optInt("fmt"),cmdStructure.optInt("tgt"),cmdStructure.optInt("sid"),cmdStructure.optInt("count"),cmdStructure.optJSONArray("sli"),i,parameter.optJSONObject(i),cmdObject.optInt("function"));
                    return true;//(JSONObject)tgtCmd.opt(key);
                }
                else
                {
                    continue;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return false;
}}
```

I read some post on that case, but I don't understand very well. I thought to post my code in this way I can understand in better way.

Other problem is that one producer is a UI thread, and I worried if there is problem to stop the UI thread for some times.

I also thought to use ConcurrentLinkedQueue because some time I need to loop on the list, and I always extract the value from the first position, but with concurrentLInkedQueue I don't know how can implementate the loop and in what way I can implementate the addMacroCmd method..

In my case I think to use lock object and ArrayList.

Do you have some suggestion ? I want to learn in better way the concurrency, but it not very easy for me :(

**EDIT :** the following is the part of code that add and remove the command :

```
public synchronized void readSensorData(String[] sensor, String target)
    {
        cmdTree.reset(); 

        for(int i=0;i<sensor.length;i++)
        {
            try 
            {
                cmdTree.populateCommandTree(sensor[i],target);
            } 
            catch (JSONException e) 
            {

            }
        }

        writeExecutor.execute(this.writeCommandTree);

    }




    /**
     * 
     * @param i
     * @param target
     * @return
     * @throws JSONException when the command requested doesn't exists
     */



    private ByteArrayOutputStream f = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    ExecutorService writeExecutor = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();

    Semaphore mutex = new Semaphore(0);

    volatile boolean diagnostic = false;
    volatile int index = 0;

    Runnable writeCommandTree = new Runnable()
    {

        @Override
        public void run() 
        {
            while(index < cmdTree.getSize())
            {
                writeCmd();
                try 
                {
                    mutex.acquire();
                } 
                catch (InterruptedException e) 
                {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }

            sendAnswerBroadcast("answer", answer); 
            answer = new JSONObject();
            index = 0;

        }

    };
```

and the mutex is release when arrive a new response .

> Addictional information :
>
> The readSensorData() is called when button on the ux (UI Thread) is
>   pressed and in same case from other Thread B. WriteCommandTree is only
>   execute in the executor (Other Thread C).
>
> I change the name of getnextcommand into getcommand
>   - getcommand(int i) is called in the callback of the response (sometime is in other thread (i'm forget to that function ...) and in writecmd inside writecommandtree
>   - getsize in the writecommandTree in the thread C

Comment: Where is the constructor called?  How about `getSize`?  `reset`? `getNextCommand`?  `populateCommandTree`?  I'm afraid it will be necessary to know about *all* of the public methods, in order to determine the correctness of this code.

Comment: I add that information in the first post :)

Comment: mmmm.... there is not a single reference to Threads in the entire question!  From that I can assume that it all runs on the UI thread? ;-)

Comment: No. The writeCommandTree run in other thread A (it is executing on the executor). And the response callback is called from the other thread B.

Answer (score 3):

Don't get headaches just for synchronizing a list, simply use the Java standard library :

```
List<Command> commands = Collections.synchronizedList(new ArrayList<>());
```

By the way, a naive implementation of this would simply to wrap an unsafe list and add `synchronized` to all the methods.

Comment: thanks :) with a list I scared from iterator.
I have to loop on that commands list, see what command are present in the list and in some times edit the object or add the new item in the list
(I do it in addMacroCmd method)
And in some case I have to keep the first object and after the second one and loop it , (es : elem 1, elem 2, elem 3, elem 1 , elem 2...) But is a problemfor thread safety to use two iterator in  in two different case ?
one for iterate all the list and one to point the next element to return in public Command getNextCommand(int i) ?

Comment: Can use a CopyOnWriteArrayList as well. See here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17853112/in-what-situations-is-the-copyonwritearraylist-suitable

Comment: Actually I wonder if my answer is ok, as the returned `Iterator` is not synchronized.

Comment: @Dici : Your answer isn't exactly wrong but it certainly doesn't address the problems in the OP's code!  ;-)

Answer (score 2):

You can use blockingQueue to achieve the same. Refer simple tutorial about blockingQueue :http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-util-concurrent/blockingqueue.html

Comment: for example an ArrayBlockingQueue ? :)
But is it a problem for the ui thread to remain blocked on an object ? In what way can I handle it in android ?

Comment: In the ArrayBlockingQueue I have to set the upper bound at instantiation time, I read the tutorial and I will choice another one :)

Comment: You can do your UI operation on another thread and update your UI once you get command in the queue. Use LinkedBlockingQueue instead of ArrayBlockingQueue, it does not have any upper bound limitation.

Comment: In my case the ux call the function with a button then start the operation, but I don't want to start one thread for each button pression. With executor I can solve this problem, right ?

Answer (score 2):

There are several problems with this code:

- It is unlikely that you need both a `ReentrantLock` and synchronization.
- The `getSize` method is not synchronized at all.  If, e.g., `reset` is called from a thread other than the one from which `getSize` is called, the program is incorrect.
- `sendCmdMap` is leaked in `CommandTree`'s constructor.  If the thread that creates the `CommandTree` is different from the thread that calls `populateCommandTree`, the program is incorrect.

Note, btw, that using a synchronized view of `cmdToSend` would not fix any of these problems.

What you need to do, here, is this:

- Producers need to seize a lock, hand a command to the `CommandTree` and then delete all references to it.
- Consumers need to seize the same lock and get a reference to a command, deleting it from the `CommandTree`.

For problems like this, there is no better reference than ["Java Concurrency in Practice"](http://jcip.net.s3-website-us-east-1.amazonaws.com/)

Comment: Hi ! Thanks for the anwer. Can you give me a little code example ? With some explanation ? 

do you mean that I have to eliminate all the lock from my code, and put one lock shared from consumer and producer ?

Comment: This is a fairly complex subject: I probably can't give you a cookbook example.  There is lots of sample code around: Search "safe publication idiom".  WRT the lock, while you don't *need* to eliminate it, I doubt that it is useful (I don't completely understand your use case).  Regardless of your use case, though, your producers and consumers absolutely *must* share a single monitor.

Comment: thanks :) However I add some other part of code in first post , I'm changing everything because actually is implemented all in wrong way... The readSensorData is called by the ux on ui thread , and this is one big error, then the write start every time the user call the above function and this is other big error.. I have to separate the :
- add new command
- write function

I think to use executor, but I have to understand how :)

Comment: Yes, I agree that it would be good to re-think this.  What is missing in your description of the problem, btw, is the key information about which functions are being called from which threads.

Comment: Thanks :) I add this information in the first post :)